# Replace double backslashes with a single backslash in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, replace, backslash

I have the following problem:

I have a script that executes an AJAX request to a server, the server returns `C:\backup\` in the preview. However, the response is `"C:\\backup\\"`. Not really a big deal, since I just thought to replace the double slashes with single ones. I've been looking around here on stack, but I could only find how to replace single backslashes with double ones, but I need it the other way around.

Can someone help me on this matter?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should do it: `"C:\\backup\\".replace(/\\\\/g, '\\')`

In the regular expression, a single `\` must be escaped to `\\`, and in the replacement `\` also.

[**edit 2021**] Maybe it's better to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
console.log(`original solution ${"C:\\backup\\".replace(/\\\\/g, '\\')}`)

// a template literal will automagically replace \\ with \
console.log(`template string without further ado ${`C:\\backup\\`}`);

// but if they are escaped themselves
console.log(`Double escaped ${`C:\\\\backup\\\\`.replace(/\\{2,}/g, '\\')}`);

// multiple escaped
console.log(`multiple escaped ${`C:\\\\\\\\backup\\\\`
  .replace(/\\{2,}/g, '\\')}`);

// don't want to replace the last \\
console.log(`not the last ${`C:\\\\\\backup\\\\`
  .replace(/\\{2,}([^\\{2,}$])/g, (a ,b) => a.slice(0,1) + b)}` );

// don't want to replace the first \\
console.log(`not the first ${`C:\\\\backup\\`.replace(/\\[^\\]$/g, '\\')}`);

// a generic tagged template to replace all multiple \\ OR //
const toSingleSlashes = (strs, ...args) => 
  strs.reduce( (a, v, i ) => 
    a.concat(args[i-1] || ``).concat(v, ``), `` )
      .replace( /(\\|\/){2,}/g, (a, b) => b );

console.log(`generic tagged template 1 ${
  toSingleSlashes`C:\\backup\\`}`);

console.log(`generic tagged template 2 ${
  toSingleSlashes`C:\\\\\\\\backup\\\\\\\\\\`}`);
  
console.log(`generic tagged template 3 ${
  toSingleSlashes`C:\\\\\\\\backup\\`}`);
  
console.log(`generic tagged template 4 ${
  toSingleSlashes`C:////////backup////`}`);

console.log(`reply to comment @chitgoks => 
"test\\\\hehehe" is by default "test\\hehehe"
so, no replacement necessary here ...`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help (niks te danken;)

Comment: This will also remove any single slash 'ab\cd' --> abcd

Comment: I have double backslash in original regex which when escaped boils down to four backslashes. Now, when I tried your regex, it converts those four backslashes to single backslash instead of double. What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: @codemirror you don't need any replacement: the string `ab\cd` itself will not contain a slash, (\c = (escape)c). Try `console.log("ab\cd")` in the developer console.

Comment: 'test\\hehehe'.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\') doesnt work

Comment: @chitgoks See edited answer (run snippet, see bottom of the logging)

Answer (score 4):

Best is to use regex to replace all occurrences:

```
C:\\backup\\".replace(/\/\//g, "/")[0]
```

this returns: `C:\backup\`

OR

use split()

```
"C:\\backup\\".split();
```

both produces your desired result

> C:\backup\

```js
console.log("using \"C:\\backup\\\".replace(/\/\//g, \"/\")")
console.log("C:\\backup\\".replace(/\/\//g, "/"));

console.log("Using \"C:\\backup\\\".split()");
console.log("C:\\backup\\".split()[0]);
```

Comment: Just wanted to note this will work with forward slash but not back slash

Comment: This will also remove any single slash 'ab\cd' --> abcd

Comment: @codemirror Good point. But if it contains '\' then you won't see it as 'ab\cd' you'll get that as 'ab\\cd' in code.

Comment: Your snippet `"C:\\backup\\".split();` does not work when testing it in the Chrome console. In addition, it would be more appropriate to write `"C:\\backup\\".split()[0]` to directly obtain the wanted string.

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone might be misleading themselves the `console.log()`. It will automatically display the expected result, regardless of whether or not you replace any of the characters.

```
const test = 'C:\\';
console.log( test ) // this will write out "C:\"
console.log( `${ test.replace( /\\{2,}/g, '\\' }` ) // this will also write out "C:\"
```

The string value is still single character escaped. However, the `console.log` is hiding that fact from you.

From what I can tell, there is no way to *actually* replace the `\\` with `\` in javascript.

the closest you can get would be to do something like this, however its still interpreted the same way

```
test.replace( /\\{2,}/g, '\u005C' )
```