# Javascript replacing double backslashed with single backslash

Tags: javascript, replace

I have been browsing lots of solutions, but somewhy haven't got anything to work.

I need to replace following string: `"i:0#.w|dev\\tauri;"` with `"i:0#.w|dev\tauri;"`

I have tried following JS codes to replace:

```
s.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\$1");

s.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
```

But have had no result. Yet following replaced my `\\` with `"`

```
s.replace(/\\/g, "\"");
```

To be honset, then I am really confused behind this logic, it seems like there should be used `\\\\` for double backshashed yet it seems to work with just `\\` for two backshashes..

I need to do this for comparing if current Sharepoint user (`i:0#.w|dev\tauri`) is on the list.

Update:

Okay, after I used `console.log();`, I discovered something interesting.

Incode: `var CurrentUser = "i:0#.w|dev\tauri";` and console.log(): `i:0#.w|dev  auri`...

C# code is following:

```
SPWeb theSite = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
SPUser theUser = theSite.CurrentUser;
return theUser.LoginName;
```

Comment: If the first two did nothing, and `s.replace(/\\/g, "\"");` replaced your `\\ ` with a single `"`, then you only had one backslash in the string to begin with. Don't confuse what you see in your debugger with the actual number of backslashes in the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace double backslashes with a single backslash in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304214/replace-double-backslashes-with-a-single-backslash-in-javascript) See also: [replace “\\” with “\” in a string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482360/replace-with-in-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: But the problem is that, even if I don't try to replace, then comparing two strings is still false

Comment: Do the semicolons have anything to do with it, or are those a typo? Please do this: do a `console.log()` with the string you are trying to modify, and do a `console.log()` with the strings you are matching it against, and observe whether there is any difference between them.

Comment: Check out my answer. That's because \t is the escape code for a tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScript strings need to be escaped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) so if you are getting a string literal with two back slashes, JavaScript interprets it as just one. In your string you are using to compare, you have \t, which is a tab character, when what you probably want is \\t. My guess is that wherever you are getting the current SharePoint user from, it is being properly escaped, but your compare list isn't.

Edit:

Or maybe the other way around. If you're using .NET 4+ [JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might be helpful. If you're still having problems it might help to show us how you are doing the comparison.

Comment: Got it work in code behind with `Regex.Escape();`, thank you! :)