# Why can String.raw handle double backslashes but regular escaping can't?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping, backslash

Matching double backslashes in a string requires two escape backslashes. But event that doesn't match in native JavaScript functions as can be seen below:

```js
const str = 'sj\\sf\sd'

str.match(/\\\\/g);                  /*null*/
str.indexOf('\\\\');                 /*-1*/
str.replace(/\\\\/, '')              /*'sj\sfsd'*/   /*<--wrong characters replaced*/
```

Whereas [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) works:

```js
const str = String.raw`sj\\sf\sd`

str.match(/\\\\/g);                  /*['\\']*/
str.indexOf('\\\\');                 /*2*/
str.replace(String.raw`\\`, '')      /*'sjsf\sd'*/
```

Similar questions have been asked about this topic but none explain the reason behind this quirkiness:

- [Replace double backslashes with a single backslash in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304214/replace-double-backslashes-with-a-single-backslash-in-javascript)
- [Javascript replacing double backslashed with single backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758010/javascript-replacing-double-backslashed-with-single-backslash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s exactly what `String.raw` is for: it does not interpret escape sequences. A backslash has a special meaning in a string, so you need to double it to get one actual backslash. With `String.raw`, (most) special characters lose their special meaning, so two backslashes are actually two backslashes. It’s used precisely when you need a string with many special characters and don’t want to worry about escaping them correctly too much.

Comment: Thanks @deceze! My question is rather why correctly escaping double backslashes produces non standard behavior. I mean why does escaping one backslash work as expected but escaping two doesn't?

Comment: You’ll have to elaborate, I don’t understand. You’re interpreting something differently from me here.

Comment: I have understood my mistake. 'sj\\sf\sd' is evaluated as 'sj\sfsd' and hence the behavior. Thanks again